# Rails: Unit Helper Tests. What does "anchors" mean in assert_select "a[class='current']" do |anchors|?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm currently going through a tutorial on testing. We're building helper methods for highlighting the tabs in the nav bar. Here are the helper methods.

```
module RecipesHelper
  def tabs(current_tab)
    content_tag(:div, links(current_tab), :id => "tabs")
  end

  def links(current_tab)
    nav_items.map do |tab_name, path|
      args = tab_name, path

      if tab_name == current_tab
         args << {:class => "current"}
      end
      link_to *args
    end.join(separator).html_safe
  end

  def nav_items
    {
      "New" => new_recipe_path,
      "List" => recipes_path,
      "Home" => root_path
    }
  end

  def separator
    content_tag(:span, "|", :class => "separator").html_safe
  end
end
```

here is one of the tests:

```
require 'test_helper'
class RecipesHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test "current tab is correct" do
    render :text => tabs("New")
    assert_select "a[class='current']" do |anchors|
      anchors.each do |anchor|
        assert_equal new_recipe_path, anchor.attributes['href']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My question is what does the `anchors` variable passed in the block? Same question for the nested block with `anchor`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation on assert_select it will get a list of all the matching elements. In this case `a[class='current']` will probably return a list of a tags(anchors).

It then it loops through that list and assert_equal if the `href` attribute of that single a tag matches the `new_recipe_path`

[assert_select docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select)